# User agent string for Chinese Characters is not read or transmitted properly through safari IOS

Tags: android, http, http-headers, mobile-safari

When I request a US web site with US user agent string (zh-cn) for mobile android device, it works fine. I 'll get the right format. But if I request the same site with same device but different build of user agent string with Chinese characters as Build/我们将 (zh-cn), the user agent is not transmitted correctly. The Chinese characters are not read or written to the request or response. So the response is for desktop instead of mobile format. The server is a linux server. I am overriding the user agent using safari Develop menu, user agent and other. 
The format of user agent is like

- http://user-agents.me/browser/mozilla50-linux-u-android-235-zh-cn-liyang-z9-buildmocordroid235-applewebkit5331-khtml-like-gecko-version40-mobile-safari5331 
  Please help me with this. If it is a encoding issue, how can i solve it? Where can i get the character set supported for China? Is it application specific ? Browser specific (accept-langauage) or HTTP 1.1 specific ?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP header fields do not really support non-ASCII characters well. Don't rely on them.